# Angular6/Firebase2 | ERROR TypeError: this.clientService.getClients(...).subscribe is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having some trouble fetching data (a list of users in this case) from Firebase.

**Version Information**

Angular Version 6

Firebase 4.13.1

Angualrfire2 5.0.0-rc.7.2

**Error seen in browser**

> DashboardComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError:
>   **this.clientService.getClients(...).subscribe is not a function**
>       at ClientsComponent.push../src/app/components/clients/clients.component.ts.ClientsComponent.ngOnInit
>   (clients.component.ts:19)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:8939)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10203)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10165)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:10798)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:10758)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (DashboardComponent.html:1)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:10750)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10147)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:10388)

**Here is my client.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Client } from '../models/Client';

@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class ClientService {

  clients: FirebaseListObservable <any[]>;
  client: FirebaseObjectObservable <any>;

  constructor(public af:AngularFireDatabase) { 
    this.clients = this.af.list('/clients') as FirebaseListObservable<Client[]>;
  }

  getClients():FirebaseListObservable <any[]> {
    return this.clients;
  }

}
```

**Here is my clients.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from '../../services/client.service';
import { Client } from '../../models/Client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients',
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients.component.css']
})
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  clients:Client[];

  constructor(public clientService:ClientService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getClients().subscribe( clients => {
      this.clients = clients;
      console.log(this.clients);
    });
  }

}
```

**And here is my Client Interface**

```
export interface Client {

    $key?:string;
    firstName?:string;
    lastName?:string;
    email?:string;
    phone?:string;
    balance?:number;

}
```

I have already tried pretty much all of the existing solutions for this error and/or for making firebase2 work with Angular 6 but I can't seem to get past this issue.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **AngularFireObject** not **FirebaseObjectObservable** and **AngularFireList** not **FirebaseListObservable**

Check this for more details: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md

```
import { AngularFireObject, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class ClientService {

  clients: Observable<any[]>;
  clientRef:AngularFireObject<any>;


  constructor(public af:AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.clientRef = db.object('item');
    this.clients = this.af.list('/clients').valueChanges();
  }

  getClients():FirebaseListObservable <any[]> {
    return this.clients;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response and help, this solved my issue. The linked documentation is also really beneficial!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the type of object returned by `this.af.list('/clients')` is not an bservable. This is with type `AngularFireList`. To convert that to observable you'll need to use `valueChanges()` OR `snapshotChanges()` methods. So, updating constructor code of your `ClientService` should work:

```
  clients: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public af:AngularFireDatabase) { 
    this.clients = this.af.list('/clients').valueChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - both answers shared here have collectively resolved my issue!